# How to use awk's gensub or alternatives to replace overlapping matches

Tags: bash, awk

I am using:

```bash
$ echo ".a.b.c." | awk '
{
  t=gensub(/.([a-z])./,"[\\1]","g",$1); print t
}'
[a]b[c]
```

I would like to end up with `[a][b][c]`. How can I get `gensub` to work with overlapping matches?

If that is not possible, how can I achieve this?

Comment: You cannot get `gensub` to work with overlapping matches.

Comment: @EdMorton thank you. any suitable alternative?

Comment: You could use match() or split() or multiple *sub()s (but then make sure to test with input like `a.[b].c`) or various other things.

Comment: @EdMorton I will accept any solution. Can you write an answer?

Comment: Please update your question to state what it is you're asking since I already answered the question you asked there and make sure to provide sample input/expected output that covers all your use cases, not just the one simple one, including cases you do NOT want to match, e.g. `a.b.` -> `a[b]` presumably.

Comment: Note that the dot matches any character in regexes, not just the literal dots you have in the input. (Which might or might not affect the ways to do this)

Comment: Something like this might also get some useful help from lookaheads/loookbehinds in Perl regexes, if you're open to using something other than AWK.

Comment: Another test case to include - `..a..` -> `.[a].` or `[[a]]`. Keep in mind that it's usually easy to match the text you want to match but much harder to not match similar text you do not want to match.

Comment: Yeah, some more input samples would help. For the given example, `echo '.a.b.c.' | sed 's/^\./[/; s/\.$/]/; s/\./][/g'` would do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
perl -pe 's{\.([a-z](?:\.[a-z])*)\.}{"[$1]" =~ s/\./][/gr}ge'
```

That is replace all the `.x.y.z.` with `[x.y.z]` inside which the `.`s are substituted with `][`.

The same in `awk`, avoiding `gensub()` which is gawk specific and would be cumbersome to use as it doesn't let you know when it succeeds:

```
awk '
  {
    while(match($0, /(\.[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz])+\./)) {
      s = substr($0, RSTART + 1, RLENGTH - 2)
      gsub(/\./, "][", s)
      $0 = substr($0, 1, RSTART - 1) "["s"]" substr($0, RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    print
  }'
```

If using current versions of `mawk` (which hasn't been localised yet) or recent versions of `gawk` or if in the C locale, you can replace `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` with `a-z`. Outside of those conditions, there's no guarantee they would be equivalent. In particular, in some locales, `[a-z]` which per-POSIX is meant to match a range of *collating elements*, not *characters* can even match more than one character, like `ddzs` in Hungarian locales.

In any case, note that to match a literal dot in regular expressions, you need `\.` or `[.]`. `.` on its own is otherwise a regexp operator that matches any single character.

Answer (score 3):

Usually regex engines don't consider overlapping matches, not the way you propose, but also not such that a latter match would consider characters inserted by a previous replacement.

In Perl, you could utilize look-behinds to match to the right of closing brackets and repeat the substitution (on the whole string) as many time as it does something. Here, assuming you meant to match letters in between literal dots (the regex `.` matches any single character):

```
% cat test.txt
.a.b.c.
..a..
.a.b  c.d.
.a]b.
% perl -pe '1 while s/(\.|(?<=\]))([a-z])\./[$2]/'  < test.txt
[a][b][c]
.[a].
[a]b  c[d]
.a][b]
```

The last line shows a false positive where an existing `]` triggers the following `b.` to match. You could avoid that by inserting some byte that is less likely to appear in the input first, and replacing them with real brackets later. E.g. the byte value 1, ^A:

```
% perl -pe '1 while s/(\.|(?<=\001))([a-z])\./[$2\001/; tr/\001/]/' < test.txt
[a][b][c]
.[a].
[a]b  c[d]
.a]b.
```

This might have other issues I didn't happen to catch. With repeat substitutions, there's some risk of getting stuck in an endless loop if the match is too loose, but that shouldn't be a risk here, since the substitution requires a literal dot and always removes at least one.

(If you did mean the `.` in the regex to match any character, then I guess e.g. `abcd` should turn in to `[b]d`, which appears odd.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a ruby:

```
echo ".a.b.c." | ruby -pe '$_.gsub!(/(?:[.][a-z](?=\.))|\./){|m| m[/^\.$/] ? "" : "[#{m[1]}]" }'
```

Or Perl:

```
echo ".a.b.c." | perl -pe 's/(?:[.]([a-z])(?=\.))|\./($1 eq "") ? "" : "[$1]" /ge'
```

Either prints:

```
[a][b][c]
```

Comment: That removes all dots though.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Isn't the output with `echo ".a.b.c."` the same as yours? I suppose the output from `echo ". . . .a.b.c."` is different but that was not specified, no?

Comment: On the output of `echo a.b.c.`, the new ones give `[a][b]c.` instead of `a[b][c]`.